# Nested Attributes Update with a different Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 Models, I face error when i am updating them.  I have used nested attributes.

```
 class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'id'

    has_many :channel_mappings , primary_key: 'channel_name', foreign_key: 'channel_name'

    attr_accessible :channel_name, :channel_mappings_attributes

    validates_presence_of :channel_name

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :channel_mappings, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

2nd Model

```
class ChannelMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'src_channel'

  belongs_to :channel, primary_key: 'channel_name', foreign_key: 'channel_name'

  attr_accessible :src_channel, :channel_name , :src_file_type 
end
```

Update Method

```
def update
        @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])

        if @channel.update_attributes(params[:channel])
            redirect_to @channel, notice: 'Channel was successfully updated.'
        else
            render action: 'edit'
        end
    end
```

Error

```
  Type: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      Message:  Couldn't find ChannelMapping with ID=ANY NAME for Channel with ID=2
```

I know it' something to do with Primary key overwritten.  Any help will be useful

db/schema.rb

```
create_table "channels", :force => true do |t|
    t.text    "channel_name",                                  :null => false
    t.string  "internal_flag",                  :limit => nil
    t.string  "exception_flag",                 :limit => nil
  end

create_table "channel_mappings", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.text    "src_channel",   :null => false
    t.text    "channel_name",  :null => false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try - `@channel.attributes = params[:channel]` instead of `@channel.update_attributes(params[:channel])`

This will also set all the attributes but without save.

Then you can call -

`@channel.save`

This will save your attributes.

The error seems to be record to be not found rather then update revert like.

Check the error log first and if needed then post it here if nothing works.

It would be better to use if else conditions as:

```
if @channel.save
#record saved
else
#error in save
end
```

Then you can know where it's going.

Comment: Well i tried your way, it still breaks.. check the code of controller and log here https://gist.github.com/ankit8898/5212677

Comment: so what's your routes.rb file contains in this context?

Comment: it just contains 'resources :channels'

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first line of Channel.rb you're setting the primary key to be 'id'. So why are you specifying primary_key='channel_name' in your associations? That seems wrong.

Also, it will be helpful to see your definition of the channels table in db/schema.rb.

**Update after additional information**

In your gist, I see that your parameters contain an id key in channel_mappings_attributes. However , your schema.rb shows that channel_mappings doesn't have an id. That's the first thing you need to fix.

Comment: Updated the question with db/schema.rb for channel and channel_mappings